# Adding a feature to onet.xml to remove the default create SP groups

Tags: development, groups

I've created a SP2010 Web Template based on a publishing site.
I've added a feature receiver which removes all default SharePoint groups (Activated through my onet.xml file). 
 Strangly enough the default groups:

Owners, Members, Visitors
Are still appearing I thought putting my feature last in the onet.xml file (just before )should only executed it at the end of the site creation but it looks creation of the default groups happens after feature activation?

Does anyone know how to create a new site with not a single default group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site provisioning process creates those groups after your site-def and features have finished running, and also after any WebAdded event receivers. The same applies to new subsites being added to the top navigation bar.

So I don't think there is any way short of a timer job or a master page delegate control that can achieve what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
CurrentWeb.BreakRoleInheritance(false);
```

deletes groups.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<ExecuteUrl Url="_layouts/Sibur.Archive/Configure.aspx?Mode=AfterCreation" />
```

to execute code to delete default groups.
This page is custom.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a worker process in the activation code that will wait for the web to be provisioned and then remove the permissions you want.